# PIL "OSError: cannot identify image file " while opening an Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to load a dataset of images using ***keras.load_img*** which returns a *PIL Image instance*, but am unable to do so due to some reason. The image was created by the following lines of code, after being generated by the ***imagaug*** module of python, which returns a *numpy array*:

```
img = augmenter(image=image)
img = Image.fromarray(img)
img.save(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Roll 1_Augmented', 'PaperPrintImgAug' + str(i+1) + '_' + str(j) + '.jpg'))
```

The iamges seem to be saved successfully and I am able to open them with any image viewer. So I do not think they are corrupted. But I get the following error whenever I try to open the images using load_img:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ae.py", line 61, in readImages
    img = load_img(folder_path[i], target_size=inputShape)
  File "/home/ies/billa/miniconda3/envs/pfprint/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 114, in load_img
    img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
  File "/home/ies/billa/miniconda3/envs/pfprint/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2896, in open
    "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f7350df9e08>
```

I tried various solutions provided online and on stackoverflow, but the situations don't seem to match with mine. Upon downloading the latest version of Pillow, I got the following change in the traceback:

```
  File "/home/ies/billa/miniconda3/envs/pfprint/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 114, in load_img
    img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
  File "/home/ies/billa/miniconda3/envs/pfprint/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2006, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
OSError: cannot identify image file
```

I suspect it might be some issue with the image encoding.
Can someone help me with this please?

### **EDIT:**

The issue was solved by saving the images as `png` files.

For the issue with JPEG files, the following is the code I used:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img

def readImages(folder_path):
    images = []
    for i in range(len(folder_path)):
        img = load_img(folder_path[i], target_size=inputShape)
        img = np.array(img)
        images.append(img)

    images = np.array(images)
    return images

augdata = glob('/home/ies/billa/Roll 1_Augmented/*')
augmentedImages = readImages(augdata)
```

Comment: Have you tried to save your images as `png` instead of `jpg`?

Comment: Try running `xxd YOURIMAGE.jpg | head -5` and pasting the output into your question after clicking `edit` so we can see if the on-disk file looks correct.

Comment: Ok, looks like a reasonable kind of JPEG. Please click `edit` under your question again and show the minimum code that fails to read the image. Thank you.

Comment: @Olha Yes changing the extension to `png` while saving worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarkSetchell the image loading worked upon changing the extension to `png`. Is there a particular reason for the `JPEG` issue?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I guess @Olha has some experience...